# Clarification for FineUploader blobUri property uploading to Azure

Tags: fine-uploader

I'm setting up React version of FineUploader to upload files to Azure going through the docs and I could use a bit more clarification on `bloburi` sent to my API when requesting a SAAS.

We're requesting the SAAS **before** uploading the file which is why I'm confused.

Say, I'm uploading a file named **my-image.jpg** into my blob container with the endpoint of `https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/my-container` on Azure.

I also want to rename the file during upload by calling a function and let's assume the function returns `89056c3d-7bb3-my-image.jpg` for file name.

Would then `https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/my-container/89056c3d-7bb3-my-image.jpg` be the bloburi I send to my API while requesting a SAAS?

In other words, are we constructing the bloburi using the azure blob storage container URI and the file name we'll end up using?

If I'm interpreting this correctly, what happens if the user is uploading multiple files? What would be the blobUri I'd have to send to request a SAAS?

UPDATE:
When my request hits my backend API to get a SAS, the blobUri comes in as `/server/upload/some-guid-value.txt`. I'm using the following options when instantiating an uploader. What am I doing wrong?

```
const uploader = new FineUploaderAzure({
    options: {
      signature: {
        endpoint: 'http://localhost:4879/api/getsas'
      },
      request: {
          containerUrl: 'https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/my-container'
      },
      uploadSuccess: {
        endpoint: 'http://localhost:4879/success'
      }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In other words, are we constructing the bloburi using the azure blob storage container URI and the file name we'll end up using?

Correct. Fine Uploader Azure constructs this for you. Be sure to verify permissions (considering the _method param that accompanies the Blob url) before returning a signature.

Comment: Just added an update to my original post. For some reason, blobUri uses `/server/upload/` as opposed to my Azure blob storage container URL. What am I doing wrong?